# If a string is longer than 10 characters, only return the last 10

Tags: python

In python I am returning numbers but I only want the last 10 numbers

Ex: 221234567890 should return 1234567890

In excel it looks like: if(len(cell) > 10, right (cell,10),.. but don't know how to do this in python

Comment: Are you asking about returning the last 10 *digits* of an *integer*?

Answer (score 3):

```py
a = 221234567890
result = a % 10000000000
```

This should work for ints and

```py
a = "221234567890"
result = a[-10:]
```

should work for strings

Comment: Non-negative integers, at least.

Comment: True, however since the author mentioned numbers I assumed non-negativity. 
In order to have a complete solution you can use `result = abs(a) % 10000000000`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = '123456789abcdefg'
a[-10:]
```